# Multi-page Table of Contents with same height?

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex

Here is the MWE, please run it twice with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[book]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english} % set language for polyglossia
% Remove "Contents" from ToC
\addto\captionsenglish{%
\renewcommand{\contentsname}%
{}%
}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents*
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\end{document}
```

You should now have a 44 pages (!) long document. However, the ToC will start at a different height on both pages:

[image]

How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a definition for `\tableofcontents` in memoir, so I assume it borrows the one from book class.

```
\documentclass[book]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english} % set language for polyglossia
% Remove "Contents" from ToC
\addto\captionsenglish{%
%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}% not needed
}
\usepackage{showframe}% debugging tool

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
  \@starttoc{toc}%
\makeatother
% alternate format: \csname @starttoc\endcsname{toc}%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't quite understand why, but this works!

Comment: Most of \tableofcontents has to do with writing "Contents".  All the real work is done by \@starttoc.